# I need to implement a linerlayout in android and populate with a list of items. I am doing so because i want the list to be non scrollable?

Tags: android-layout

final LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlist);
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                textlength = et.getText().length();
                array_sort.clear();
                for (i = 0; i < namelist.length; i++) {

```
                if (textlength <= namelist[i].length()) {
                    if (et.getText()
                            .toString()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    (String) namelist[i].subSequence(0,
                                            textlength))) {
                        array_sort.add(namelist[i]);
                        if (et.getText().length() == 0) {
                            // array_sort.remove(namelist[i]);
                            array_sort.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just instantiate new TextView on the fly and add them to your layout.

```
TextView view = new TextView(context);
l.addView(view);
```